# Hovering over link, toggle div visibility until mouse leaves BOTH link and div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The usual question is: "How do I hover over one thingOne and make thingOneFriend slide open?"

Add to that: "How do I keep thingOneFriend open until the mouse leaves either element?"

Plus the caveat that thingOneFriend is NOT contained in thingOne.

So:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="blerg" id="#thingOne"></li>
        <li><a href="blarg" id="#thingTwo"></li>
        <li><a href="blorg" id="#thingThree"></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="thingOneFriend">I'm normally hidden</div>
    <div id="thingTwoFriend">Me too.</div>
    <div id="thingThreeFriend">Word.</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bu20o10h/1/)

I've tried:

```
$(“#thingOne”).hover(function () {
    $("#thingOneFriend").slideToggle(400);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery libary (in JS Language) [`.mouseOver()` method](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Here is an example for your issue:

```
<a href="#" id="hover">onHover this will open a little window</a>
<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">Hello</div>
```

and the script:

```
$( "#hover" ).mouseover(function() {
    $( "#hidden" ).css( "display", "block" );
});
$( "#hover" ).mouseout(function() {
    $( "#hidden" ).css( "display", "none" );
});
```

You can use [onmouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) to keep visibility hidden when mouse leaving the link.
You might also read about the method [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

http://jsfiddle.net/m7nqoqpr/1/

Comment: @Octavian http://jsfiddle.net/hjo4291t/1/ You have named the id's like this #ThingOne and you should name them normaly. Dont forget to accept my answer :)

Comment: Good catch - copied and pasted and missed it. Added mouse out to the fiddle. One thing left - need to keep the div open when hovering over the div itself. http://jsfiddle.net/m7nqoqpr/

Comment: @octavian its already keeps the div open when you hover 'blerg' link

Comment: Yes, but closes when you leave the blerg link to hover over the thingOneFriend div.

Comment: @Octavian as I said in my answer you should read about it here http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61934/discussion-between-exclusiv3-and-octavian).